# Unanswered Questions where OP gets the answer

Tags: discussion

I find that there are many questions which are marked as Unanswered but when checked , are usually ones of homework questions where a user comments the OP's mistake and the problem is solved .
Shouldnt these questions be deleted as no external user will find it useful ?

Comment: Related: [answers in comments](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/964/50583)

Comment: Also, if you find HW questions that are just about finding a mistake and have not been closed, I encourage you to flag them for closing.

Comment: Note that [general Flagging](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) requires 15 rep while Flagging for closure requires 50 rep.

Comment: Under the appropriate circumstances closed questions will be [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). I would guess this will catch most questions closed as homework.